# UIDocumentMenuViewController blank Options

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, file-import

I have a problem with iCloud file import
I'm getting empty options after I choose the place to import from (iCloud, google drive, dropbox ... etc)
I have data on iCloud drive and the entitlements are right

So what is wrong with this code or is there anything about the settings may cause this problem?

here is the code

```
@IBAction func selectionButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let types = [kUTTypePDF as String ,kUTTypePNG as String, kUTTypeImage as String,kUTTypeJPEG as String]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
        let documentMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
        documentMenu.delegate = self
        self.viewController?.present(documentMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentMenu.delegate = self
        self.viewController?.present(documentMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        if controller.documentPickerMode == .import {
// do staff
        }
    }
```

---

Here is what I get When I run the app on iOS 10

When I Press choose File

[image: When i Press choose File]

then after pressing on iCloud

[image: After pressing on iCloud]

That's what I get if I run the app on iOS 9:

[image: That's what I get if I run the app on iOS 9]

---

I'm sure I have data there like here in the iCloud Drive application

[image: Dirve Data]

And the entitlement

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when trying to present a already used Instance of the `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.
I was instantiating it lazily like this:

```
lazy var documentMenuController: UIDocumentMenuViewController = {
    let controller = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["com.adobe.pdf"], in: .import)
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}()
```

Which produced this error every time except the first time.

So I changed the code to this:

```
var documentMenuController: UIDocumentMenuViewController {
    let controller = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["com.adobe.pdf"], in: .import)
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}
```

To obtain a fresh instance on every access of the property.